# Is it a good way to call web api in asp.net mvc controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

We have web application in asp.net mvc using razor code. Now along with web app we need android app. So whatever operations done in mvc controller need to shift in web API controller. So is there any way to convert mvc controller to web API controller? and is it a good approach to call web API in mvc controller?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common scenario these days.

To answer your question, no you cannot simply convert an MVC controller to WebApi. For one the API is stateless so you need to take that into consideration.

My suggestion is to create a separate WebApi2 project and create the controllers you need there. There may not even be a 1 to 1 correlation to your MVC controllers.

Think of this web api project as your data layer, in a way. It will simply provide the data you need, maybe create some new things and that's it. If you need to save / load data from a database then that's where you do it so both the UI and mobile app use the same data store basically.

Start small, create one controller first with one method in it and then have your MVC app call it and use the data. When you deploy somewhere you will deploy two things :

1. The UI app
2. The WebApi project

This means you will need to keep the URL of the WebApi project somewhere so your UI knows about it.

Once you achieve this separation move to your mobile app and call the same WebApi method you've just implemented for the UI project. This will be your Proof of Concept basically.

An Api comes with its own set of rules and challenges, for example :

1. which methodology are you going to use? REST or not.
2. How are you going to secure it?

I suggest looking into OAuth2 with JWT for security and if you are interested I can provide some links.

Here is the blog of Taiseer Joudeh, who does a lot of stuff on OAuth2, you'll find loads of articles on the subject there : http://bitoftech.net/taiseer-joudeh-blog/

Here is an article I wrote on OAuth2 and JWT which will take you through a lot of different things :

https://eidand.com/2015/03/28/authorization-system-with-owin-web-api-json-web-tokens/

Comment: why not create a common `Services` dll, where you have all your business logic, both WebApi and Mvc referencing it?

Comment: that's an implementation detail which I tend to leave to the other party to deal with. The main idea here is to provide an API which can be used both from a MVC and a mobile app

Comment: so every mvc request, calls another web api to get the data? why introduce this overhead ?

Comment: @CristiPufu because manageability > micro-optimisation. Having a web app back onto REST APIs is not uncommon and having all access to a set of business logic centralised through a single interface (i.e. Web API) is a very good thing from an operations and IO perspective.

Comment: well, you have a choice, either do things the same way and treat MVC just like any other client, mobile or not, or do things separately and deal with it that way. If I were you I would provide another answer with your solution. It will be a lot more helpful than comments.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion guys. So i think using asp.net mvc(razor) will be good way to consume the web api, right?

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu you can provide the links. It will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: ok, links added to main answer, good luck!

Comment: Thanks @AndreiDragotoniu

Answer (score 0):

I always see a controller as a hatch. My controllers never has any business logic. Any logic comes to seperate libraries, which can easily include an API.
be sure the make use of the await keywords for async methods when using API's.

So just replacing your controller logic to an api should work, If you not using many function from the base class which you inherit from webcontroller.

Comment: Typically this results in something like `[WebApiController]->[WebApiAdapter]->[BusinessModel]` and `[MvcController]->[MvcAdapter]->[BusinessModel]` -- of course an arguably cleaner model is to make your MVC app just make HTTP requests to your API - that way everything goes through the same door.

Comment: agreed! no need for controllers if your front-end can pick the same information from any API!